# Convert Dll to XSD scheme

Tags: c#, xml, dll, xsd, schema

I want to convert C# to XSD. I found on Microsoft site possible solution for me ([XML Schema Definition Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-def-tool-gen))

It has two simple methods:

- xsd mySchema.xsd - Parse XSD to DLL
- xsd MyFile.dll   - Parse DLL to XSD

I start CMD as administrator and execute the command, but I have a problem: Access is denied.
[image]

I try something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oryzlo07cwQ), but no results. What I can do?

Comment: What's the output of `where xsd.exe`?

Comment: I found it on <C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools>

Comment: And just executing `xsd` prints the usage information? Has the DLL file been downloaded from the Internet/Intranet? If that's the case, it probably needs to get unblocked in the properties dialog.

Comment: The file is created from build - Visual studio on release mode. File is ok, but I can't start XSD.exe from some reason.

Comment: Is there some other way to generate XSD FOR EXISTING CLASSES

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be executed in Developer CMD.
Check for the Developer command prompt in windows search with the similar version of your visual studio.

Comment: Look asked dateTime 

Comment: Lolz, writing it for the 2k kids :P